# Foreach Loop not running in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to send a request to external API using guzzle, but not `foreach` is not running.

```
public function recursub() {
  $usersCheck = User::where('trialExpires', '<=', Carbon::now());
      //Get all Check User
      foreach ($usersCheck as $user) {
        dd('Hello');
      $url = 'https://api.##############';
      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
        'headers' => [
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.'#########################',
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
   
        'form_params' => [
         'authorization_code' => $user->authorization_code,
         'customer' => $user->email,
         //'plan' => '#######################',
     ] 
      ]);
```

It worked if I hardcode the value into the form paramas.

Comment: Should you add `->get()` after `User::where('trialExpires', '<=', Carbon::now());`?

Comment: Ops, thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function recursub() {
  $usersCheck = User::where('trialExpires', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
      //Get all Check User
      foreach ($usersCheck as $user) {
        dd('Hello');
      $url = 'https://api.##############';
      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
        'headers' => [
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.'#########################',
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
   
        'form_params' => [
         'authorization_code' => $user->authorization_code,
         'customer' => $user->email,
         //'plan' => '#######################',
     ] 
      ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

get() method is used to get data in array, so now you have to add get() method in the last of the query. Here is the code below:

```
$usersCheck = User::where('trialExpires', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
```

get() method is used for getting multiple records and first is used for single record.